Subtract the previous number when another row is not NA in R
This is a simplified data example.
df <- data.frame(
  SU = c(1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA),
  TIME = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60),
  AMT = c(5, 5, NA, NA, 5, 5)
)

I want to generate a new column TFDS, if is.na(SU) == TRUE, using TIME subtract previous AMT not NA row's TIME.
This is what I want.



SU
TIME
AMT
TFDS




1
10
5
NA


1
20
5
NA


NA
30
NA
10


NA
40
NA
20


NA
50
5
30


NA
60
5
10



I tried dplyr::lag(), but the output was not what I want.
library(dplyr) 

df <- df |> 
  mutate(
    TFDS = if_else(
      is.na(SU) == TRUE, TIME - lag(TIME)[!is.na(AMT)], NA
    ))

I believe dplyr::lag() should be used there, but how to set [!is.na(AMT)]?

I cannot understand. What does "if is.na(SU) == TRUE, using TIME subtract previous AMT not NA row's TIME" mean?

You can create a temporary column and use tidyr::fill() to fill down from the TIME value that corresponds to the last non-NA AMT value, then subtract values using lag():
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df |>
  mutate(tmp = if_else(!is.na(AMT), TIME, NA)) |>
  fill(tmp, .direction = "down") |>
  mutate(TFDS = if_else(is.na(SU), TIME - lag(tmp), NA)) |>
  select(-tmp)

#   SU TIME AMT TFDS
# 1  1   10   5   NA
# 2  1   20   5   NA
# 3 NA   30  NA   10
# 4 NA   40  NA   20
# 5 NA   50   5   30
# 6 NA   60   5   10

